# ProgressDialog in AsyncTask in Fragment crashes

Tags: java, asynchronous, android-asynctask, fragment, progressdialog

I have a `Fragment` with `AsyncTask` inside an `Activity`. But i get this exception when i run the search:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference.
```

It has something to do with the Fragment not knowing if the Activity is running, but i don't know how to fix it.
Please help.
Here is the code:

```
class Send_API extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            if (movieList != null){
                movieList.clear();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            dialog.setMessage("Searching...");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String queryString = null;
            try {
                queryString = "" +
                        "s=" + URLEncoder.encode(txt, "utf-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            }
            return HttpHandler.get(params[0], queryString);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            dialog.dismiss();
            if (result == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error getting results...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                try {
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

                    JSONArray searchArray = json.getJSONArray("Search");

                    for (int i = 0; i < searchArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject searchObject = searchArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String title = searchObject.getString("Title");
                        String type = searchObject.getString("Type");
                        String year = searchObject.getString("Year");
                        String imdbID = searchObject.getString("imdbID");
                        String poster_url = searchObject.getString("Poster");
                        movieList.add(new Movie(title, type, year, imdbID, poster_url));

                        Log.e(TAG, "MovieList is " + movieList);


                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "error parsing results...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please post full logcat

Comment: please show us the code where you create and execute `Send_API'

Answer (score 0):

```
  dialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
```

`getActivity()` will return null when you're initializing your `Fragment`. You'll have to wait until `onAttach()` in the fragment lifecycle for it to return non-null.

That's the reason for the `NPE`.

Overall, don't have non-default constructors in fragments. Set up the fragment view only in `onCreateView()`.

Comment: Thank you, but i didn't understand, what must i do on `onAttach` take the `context` from there?

Comment: It still doesn't work, even after i add: `@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass base context to your asynctask and replace `getActivity()` with it or `getApplicationContext()`